VS Code - Unable to activate the Apex Language Server - spawn ENOTDIR
I'm trying to resolve Apex Language Server error in VS Code:
Unable to activate the Apex Language Server - spawn ENOTDIR

Supported Java version has been installed and is already set in VS Code settings
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
CLI tools are up to date
@salesforce/cli/2.38.7 darwin-x64 node-v20.11.1
Uninstalling and re-installing VS Code did not work


Turned out I needed change
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
to
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home
